# How to create a jar from a github Project

Tags: eclipse, github, jar

I want a jar file for the project https://github.com/tsantalis/RefactoringMiner but I don't see any link on the site which gives me jar file and there is no POM.xml 
I need to run the project on Eclipse

Comment: It is a Gradle, not a Maven project. So there is a `build.gradle` instead of a `pom.xml` file. The JARs are in the `RefactoringMiner.zip` file of the release: https://github.com/tsantalis/RefactoringMiner/releases

Answer (score 1):

From the page you linked:

> In order to build the project, run ./gradlew jar (or gradlew jar, in Windows) in the project's root directory. Alternatively, you can generate a complete distribution zip including all runtime dependencies running ./gradlew distZip.